# OnEvent API in EWS API is listening twice while receiving every single email in inbox

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I am creating a new API which will read the email using the onEvent notification method, I will send the mail to another email. While sending the mail to another mail its getting sent twice.

I have tried to filter out the duplicate by storing the id in a hash map and checking for the id in the second time the notification method is getting triggered when it matches the id, I will not send mail. but this didn't work properly.

My streaming notification:

```
StreamingSubscription subscription = exchangeService.subscribeToStreamingNotification(folder,EventType.NewMail);  
StreamingSubscriptionConnection conn = new StreamingSubscriptionConnection(exchangeService,30); conn.addSubscription(subscription );  
conn.addNotificationEvent(new StreamingsubscriptionConnection.INotificationEventDelegate())
    { @override 
    public void notificationEventDelegate(object sender, NotificationEventArgs args){
         StreamingSubscription subscription = args.getSubscription(); 
            for(NotificationEvent event : args.getEvents()){
                 if(event instanceof FolderEvent){
                     FolderEvent folderEvent = (FolderEvent) event; 
                 } else if (event instanceof ItemEvent){
                     ItemEvent itemEvent = (ItemEvent) event; } else{ logger.error("Unsupported event" + event.getClass)
                 }
else{
 logger.error("Unsupported event" + event.getClass) 
}
```

Comment: So which Id are you referring to ? have you tried actually binding to the Message ? Probably using the InternetMessageId would be a better way of avoiding duplicates

Comment: Hi, I am using the itemId to bind

Comment: So check the InternetMessageId then that won't be duplicated

Comment: I have used a global hash map to store the value of the item Id or Internet Id. So I have created a logic like if the id already exist in that hash map the mail will not be sent but the problem with this the hash map getting cleared in the middle of the operation so when the mail is about to send for the second time it checks the condition,since its empty now the id which was added into the old hash map is again added to the new hash map(cleared one) and the mail is getting sent again.

Comment: You need to fix your hash map logic issue (or probably do it another way if its restriction of the method your trying to use), getting duplicates in notifications isn't that uncommon and is a condition that should be easy to handle with client side logic and necessary for the process your trying to implement.

Comment: Thanks its working now